# android gradle test path

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, android-studio

I am trying to set gradle build system for a libgdx application. 
As you might know, libgdx has a standard project structure, which is created by its tool.
There usually is a shared module, which is a pure java lib, then there is a java application module as well as an android module.
Now I am trying to add a test directory to android module, and I cannot make the android studio recognize it. 
I add

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
        resources {
           srcDir 'src/resources'
        }
   }
   test {
       java {
         srcDir 'src/test/java'
       }
  }
}
```

But I cannot make android studio understand this. Reimport doesn't work, and I couldn't find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android plugin doesn't support a `test` sourceSet yet; only `instrumentTest`, intended for running on-device tests.